# What does 「～知ってください」 mean in The Blue Hearts' song リンダリンダ?

Tags: translation, song-lyrics

The Blue Heart's 1987 song 「リンダリンダ」 is available translated all over the internet, but the most common translations seem contentious to me when it comes to the following verse:

> もしも僕がいつか君と出会い話し合うなら
>
> そんな時はどうか愛の意味を知って下さい

The second line of this verse often gets translated as ["Please teach me the meaning of love"](http://www.animelyrics.com/jpop/thebluehearts/rindarinda.htm), but I can't really find any examples of 知る used to mean teach/explain anywhere.

Should this line actually be translated as "Please know the meaning of love" or something similar? Or is "Please teach me the meaning of love" correct in this case?

Comment: Animelyrics is hardly a credible source. Most "other" sources I found via a google search look like a copy from animelyrics, or vice versa. It's interesting to see how information spreads throughout the net. Here's a translation I found that seems to be independent: http://heresiarchy.tumblr.com/post/46113333464/the-blue-hearts-translation (I didn't take a closer look, I'm not claiming this one is better.)

Answer (score 3):

I bet that is a mistranslation and you are right.
By no means 知ってください can mean anything like "teach me". <strike>I think.</strike>

Comment: Not think. Definitely.

Comment: Yes, definitely.